# How do I test code that uses ExecutorService without using timeout in Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a class.

```
public class FeedServiceImpl implements FeedService {
    private final Map<FeedType, FeedStrategy> strategyByType;
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); 

    public FeedServiceImpl(Map<FeedType, FeedStrategy> strategyByType) {
        if (strategyByType.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("strategyByType map is empty");
        this.strategyByType = strategyByType;
    }

    @Override
    public void feed(LocalDate feedDate, FeedType feedType, String uuid) {
        if (!strategyByType.containsKey(feedType)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not supported feedType: " + feedType);
        }
        executorService.submit(() -> runFeed(feedType, feedDate, uuid));
    }


    private FeedTaskResult runFeed(FeedType feedType, LocalDate feedDate, String uuid) {
        return strategyByType.get(feedType).feed(feedDate, uuid);
    }
}
```

How can I verify with Mockito that `strategyByType.get(feedType).feed(feedDate, uuid)` was called when I call feed method?

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FeedServiceImplTest {
    private LocalDate date = new LocalDate();
    private String uuid = "UUID";

    private FeedService service;
    private Map<FeedType, FeedStrategy> strategyByType;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        strategyByType = strategyByTypeFrom(TRADEHUB);
        service = new FeedServiceImpl(strategyByType);
    }

    private Map<FeedType, FeedStrategy> strategyByTypeFrom(FeedSource feedSource) {
        return bySource(feedSource).stream().collect(toMap(identity(), feedType -> mock(FeedStrategy.class)));
    }

    @Test
    public void feedTest() {
        service.feed(date, TH_CREDIT, uuid);
        verify(strategyByType.get(TH_CREDIT), timeout(100)).feed(date, uuid);
    }
}
```

This is my version. But I don't want to use Mockito timeout method. It's in my opinion not a good solution. Help me please!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I test code that are dependent on executors I usually try to use an executor implementation that runs the task immediately in the same thread as submitted in order to remove all the hassle of multithreading. Perhaps you can add another constructor for your `FeedServiceImpl` class that lets you supply your own executor? The google guava lib has a `MoreExecutors.directExecutor()` method that will return such an executor. That would mean your test setup would change to something like:

```
service = new FeedServiceImpl(strategyByType, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
```

The rest of the test code should then work as it is, and you can safely drop the timeout verification mode parameter.

Answer (score 3):

A little improvement for @Per Huss answer so you won't have to change your constructor you can use **ReflectionTestUtils** class which is part of the **spring-test** package.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    strategyByType = strategyByTypeFrom(TRADEHUB);
    service = new FeedServiceImpl(strategyByType);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service , "executorService", MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService());
}
```

Now in the tests your executorService will implement the MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService() and not  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().

Comment: Although it's field injecting an instance (which can be scary and leads to some code not being tested), this is the best solution unless dependency injecting the executor. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a *real* `FeedStrategy` (rather than a mocked one, as suggested in another answer) then you'll need a way for the `FeedStrategy` to *somehow* indicate to the test thread when it is finished. For example, by using a `CountDownLatch` or setting a flag which your test can wait on.

```
public class FeedStrategy {

    private boolean finished;

    public void feed(...) {
        ...
        this.finished = true;
    }

    public boolean isFinished() {
        return this.finished;
    }
}
```

Or perhaps the `FeedStrategy` has some side effect which you could wait on?

If any of the above are true then you could use [Awaitility](http://www.awaitility.org/) to implement a waiter. For example:

```
    @Test
    public void aTest() {
        // run your test

        // wait for completion
        await().atMost(100, MILLISECONDS).until(feedStrategyHasCompleted());

        // assert 
        // ...
    }

    private Callable<Boolean> feedStrategyHasCompleted() {
        return new Callable<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                // return true if your condition has been met
                return ...;
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a mock for FeedStrategy.class visible to your test, so that you will be able to verify if the FeedStrategy.feed method was invoked:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FeedServiceImplTest {
private LocalDate date = new LocalDate();
private String uuid = "UUID";

private FeedService service;
private Map<FeedType, FeedStrategy> strategyByType;
private FeedStrategy feedStrategyMock;


@Before
public void setUp() {
    strategyByType = strategyByTypeFrom(TRADEHUB);
    service = new FeedServiceImpl(strategyByType);
    feedStrategyMock = Mockito.mock();
}

private Map<FeedType, FeedStrategy> strategyByTypeFrom(FeedSource feedSource) {
    return bySource(feedSource).stream().collect(toMap(identity(), feedType -> feedStrategyMock));
}

@Test
public void feedTest() {
    service.feed(date, TH_CREDIT, uuid);
    verify(feedStrategyMock).feed(date, uuid);
}
}
```